# php artisan serve new session every request

Tags: session, laravel

On my local machine, for development I am running WAMP and sometimes use php artisan serve for running my applications while developing.

What I found out is that every page request is creating a new sessionId in app/storage/sessions. For whatever reason, this is only occuring when I use artisan serve and hit the app at localhost:8000. When I go through the apache address of my webapps directory projectname/public, sessions are being retained as expected.

The first I noticed the problem is when I added the csrf token and was having errors submitting forms.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same issue too below is what I haved used to solve it.
I created new virtual host in

- C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
- Went to C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\httpd.conf and I uncomment this Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
- then went and configured my virtualhost like

ServerAdmin webmaster@virtualhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/virtualhostwebsitefolder"
    ServerName ngosfunds.com
    ErrorLog "logs/ngosfunds.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/ngosfunds.com-access.log" common

Comment: I am facing similar problem but with browser-sync (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391280/php-session-issue-with-browser-sync-laravel-artisan-serve) and I would like to try with your method to see if it does help solve problem or not. But I don't understand the last part - `then went and configured my virtualhost like...`. Hope you can explain more detail for beginner like me. Thank you.